# Excel, how can i count values ​next to cells with the same name

Tags: excel, office365

Imagine that we have this table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahc4D.png)

How can i count apples ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order  to avoid your question being downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will be useful to you

```
=SOMMEPROD((A2:A5="Apple")*(B2:B5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIF as follows,
=SUMIF (range, criteria, [sum_range])
In your case this is
=SUMIF(A2:A5,"Apples",B2:B5)